# Android StateListDrawable bug?

Tags: android, statelistdrawable

i have `StateListdrawable` in xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_off" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_on" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_off" />

</selector>
```

i have `GridView`  images which has `StateListDrawable`, and programically try to change drawable state with

```
    if(mSelected.contains(photo)){
        view.findViewById(R.id.selector).setActivated(true);
    }
```

images which selected changes state, but when i click his state not change, i'm sorry i can't explain what i want, my english is worse

i try to explain it

if `mSelected.contains(photo) [state - active] -> [checked_on.jpg]` when i click ->
state drawable begins from first and ignoring my programically state changes

**==Edit==**

Adapter Item --

```
private View getPhoto(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        if(convertView == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.gallery_photo_item, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView mPhoto = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.photoview);

        Photo photo = (Photo) getItem(position - COLUMNS_NUM);

        if(mSelected.contains(photo)){
            view.findViewById(R.id.selector).setActivated(true); // here i change my drawable state because it's front of my imageView
        }

        mLoader.displayImage(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + File.separator + photo.id,
                mPhoto);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order of the states. They are checked top to bottom, and the first one that matches the situation is used. So that means that the first two are always used. This should work:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_on"  />
    <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_off" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked_off" />
</selector>
```

Comment: No, it's not helped, when i programically change state to active, and then click on this his state check active again

Comment: How do the items inside the GridView look like?